# Conda glibc dependency conflict

Tags: python, build, conda, glibc, conda-build

I get a weird error when I try to build a conda package.

```
$ conda-build pkg2

....
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed   
....
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - pkg1 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.17
```

It looks to me as if `glibc 2.17` satisfies all three requirements, however conda thinks there is a conflict.

To clarify, `pkg2` depends on another package that I have built locally, `pkg1`. `pkg1` is a C++ library with a python interface, that depends on `libfftw`. I could not find `libfftw` on conda, so had to install it via yum on the build host, which runs CentOS7 with `glibc 2.17`, hence the dependency.

In `pkg1` `meta.yaml` I have:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - sysroot_linux-64  >=2.17  [linux]
```

`pkg2 meta.yaml`:

```
requirements:
  host:
    - pkg1
  run:
    - pkg1
```

Comment: "*I could not find libfftw on conda*" - it's just [`fftw`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fftw), but includes libs and include headers in the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @merv for the `fftw` tip.

I strongly suspect that the issue was caused by a mixture of packages from `conda-forge` and Anaconda `default` channels in the same environment. According to conda developers, this is considered a bad practice. Once I have changed it around to using `conda-forge` only, the problems went away.

Comment: Ah yes, the channel mixing issue. Haven't seen this come up with `conda build` before, so good to know it's a possibility.

Comment: @Evgeny Tanhilevich

Comment: How do you make this switch?
Can you mix packages from mamba and conda?

Comment: I dont know if this is related enough, but I had issue with ```mamba install -c bioconda perl-bioperl``` after making an env with mamba (```mamba create -n foo python=3.10``` then ```conda activate foo``` then ``mamba install r-base```) where I got the error ``` - nothing provides perl >=5.22.0,<5.23.0 needed by perl-bioperl-1.6.924-1``` so I tried: ```mamba create -n foo -c bioconda python=3.10 perl-bioperl-1.6.924-1``` but this have me an almost identical error: ```- nothing provides requested perl-bioperl-1.6.924-1```

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was that I made the environment with python version 3.10 and it is/was/seems like that is compatible.